# Typing lag in Eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

I noticed an annoying typing lag in Eclipse Neon for Linux. Each time I type a letter, it appears on the screen with a little delay (less than a second). It happens in all source files, regardless of their size.

Any clues on how to get rid of this?

Comment: Nobody has an answer on this?

Comment: This did the trick for me https://askubuntu.com/questions/760302/eclipse-neon-mars-is-very-slow-hangs-on-a-fresh-16-04-install-and-upgrade. It messes up the visual appearance a little, but at least it speeds it up.

Comment: Thanks. I was using it in Windows. I found another way to solve it, by increasing the size of the initial memory i allocate to 512MB (`-Xms512m`) in my eclipse.ini. But if that fixed your problem, i think it would be best to spend a minute or two to write your own answer to the question and accept it. Just saying. Cheers.

Comment: The trick that I did is more like a workaround. Besides this, it messes up the UI a little, so I don't think it's quite a valid answer.

Answer (score 8):

For me closing the "Project Explorer" solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on a Windows 10 PC. In the eclipse.ini file, changing all values set to 256M or 256m to 512M/512m solves the problem, assuming your computer has enough memory to handle this limit upgrade. Happened only when I was working on two different projects with many tabs opened.

Comment: Had the same problem, but did not help. Was worth a try. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Eclipse still becomes laggy if I have it open 24/7 for a few days on my computer. Closing and restarting the application always removes the lag at this point.

Comment: Changed -Xms256m to -Xms512m as suggested and the lagging is gone completely, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and disabling the [Content assistant](https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/code_assist.htm) solved the lag issue. It is not the best solution but for now I am triggering the assistant manually using control+space (in Windows).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a Eclipse Photon of Windows 10.
I have tried the following methods:

1. Edit eclipse.ini
2. Close all validation
3. Modify Content assistat
4. Upgrade eclipst to Simrel
5. Change theme
6. change jdk
7. **Close Project Explorer and replace it with Package Explorer**

Only point 7 is working

Comment: in case of e.g. scripting perl - replace "Project Explorer" with "Script Explorer"